# CakePHP Test Suite Cache and mockobject autoload error

Tags: cakephp, phpunit, cakephp-2.3

My specifications:
CakePHP 2.3
PHPUnit 3.6.10

When i test my app on the console over cakephp unit testing, there is always an error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function phpunit_mockobject_autoload() in /usr/share/pear/PHPUnit/Util/GlobalState.php on line 378
```

When i test my app over the CakePHP Test Suite 2.3, the test checks true when i save the TestCase, but when i restart the test, i get a old error message from my testing. I think it´s a cache problem. Because after saving my TestCase, the test success. And yes i have clean up the Browser Cache.

I think my pear install is broken, i hope someone can help me please.

It is possible that, this two problems have the same issue?

Comment: Did you try to run the test on the console? Not all tests work properly when tested through the web interface. Also show your test code.

Comment: When i test it over the console, i get the "Call to undefined function phpunit_mockobject_autoload()" error

Comment: I agree - I think the PEAR install is broken.  Try removing it and installing it again: https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/installation.html --- try to use the composer install, works for me on OSX and Ubuntu